# Is it possible to send Claims when using WS-Federation passive sign-in in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization, adfs2.0, ws-federation

We have successfully implemented ADFS sign-in into an ASP.NET application (MVC). What we need to do, however, is to authorize users based on AD group membership.

We cannot setup the authorization rules in the ADFS configuration because the group which the user needs to be a member of, depends on some parameter that we would like to send as a claim.

I cannot find a way to actually send claims when signing in using WS-Federation. Is this at all possible? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You need to elaborate. ADFS sends some basic claims OOTB so what problem are you experiencing?

Also if you use the Groups claim rule you get the groups in the claims as Roles.

Claims rules can do a lot. What rules do you want to create? Why can't you use the claims rules language?